How to label ipywidget dropdowns in goglecolab
I have around 20 dropdown boxes containing unique column values (str) for fungi characteristics. Is there a way to label them, e.g. 'colour', 'gill-size'?
import ipywidgets as widgets

# Create a dictionary of dropdowns, one for each variable
dropdowns = {}
for col in df.columns:
  options = list(df[col].unique())
  options.append
  options.append('unknown')
  dropdowns[col] = widgets.Dropdown(
  options=options,
  value=df[col].iloc[0] 
        )
          

# Display the dropdowns
(widgets.VBox(list(dropdowns.values())))

i have tried label=col and key=col
